# Gradle parent project not using child repositories?

Tags: java, gradle

That's how I would interpret it. I have a multi-project build with 2 modules: codec and content. When I try to build the project it says it can't find repositories. But when building individual modules, no errors. Also, evaluationDependsOn(':codec') doesn't seem to help.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :multiproject-unified:unspecified > multiproject-unified:codec:unspecified
```

**parent build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':codec')
    compile project(':content')
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'codec',
        'content'
```

**:codec build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
}
```

**:content build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I have had the same problem, never really found an answer. I usually hand add the dependency to the parent.

Comment: Why should you use such a configuration? Adding the repo to the parent is a common practice, just asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: @MarkBramnik hmm, true, makes sense. :D But still, I think it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @MarkBramnik we use modules to hide vendor specific code. The child module has vendor specific maven repos, now I need to add that maven repo both the child and the parent, which is kinda ugly, because the parent itself doesn't contain any vendor code :-S

Comment: @bah Did you manage to find any solution for this? In my case the child sub project has authorisation on one of repositories and I would not love to pull out those details to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your repositories for the entire project in the parent:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it is not nice to pull out child sub project implementation details to the parent project.